How can I fix the SI units in this program?
I have written the following script to run an MC simulation of polymers.
The script is producing very small total energies.
What am I doing incorrectly? My suspect is that the unit conversion is incorrect. However, I specifically don't know what is incorrect because I have used the most relevant units and initial values.
How can I fix the SI units in this program?
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

# Global Parameters (Updated to SI Units)
polymer_chain_vec = []
N = 50  # Number of beads in the polymer chain
sim_steps_int = 100000  # Number of Monte Carlo steps
sigma = 1.0e-10  # Lennard-Jones sigma (m)
periodic_boundary_int = 1.0e-9  # Size of the periodic box (m)
cutoff_distance = 2.5 * sigma  # Lennard-Jones cutoff distance (m)
max_atom_distance_float = 3.8e-10  # Maximum atom displacement (m)
epsilon = 1.0  # Lennard-Jones epsilon (J)
temperature_float = 500  # Temperature (K)
k_B = 1.380649e-23  # Boltzmann constant (J/K)
avogadro_number = 6.022e23  # Avogadro's number (mol^-1)

def write_txt(file_name_str, text_str):
    """Write text to a file."""
    with open(file_name_str, 'a') as f:
        f.writelines(text_str)

def apply_boundary_condition(point_pt):
    """Apply periodic boundary conditions to a point."""
    x = point_pt[0] % periodic_boundary_int
    y = point_pt[1] % periodic_boundary_int
    return [x, y]

def get_distance(point_one_pt, point_two_pt):
    """Calculate the minimum image distance between two points."""
    dx = abs(point_one_pt[0] - point_two_pt[0])
    dy = abs(point_one_pt[1] - point_two_pt[1])

    # Apply minimum image convention
    dx = dx if dx <= periodic_boundary_int / 2 else periodic_boundary_int - dx
    dy = dy if dy <= periodic_boundary_int / 2 else periodic_boundary_int - dy

    return math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)

def get_point_at_radius(current_point_pt, radius_double):
    """Generate a random point at a given radius around the current point."""
    angle = random.random() * math.pi * 2
    x = (math.cos(angle) * radius_double) + current_point_pt[0]
    y = (math.sin(angle) * radius_double) + current_point_pt[1]
    return apply_boundary_condition([x, y])

def lj_energy_func(r_float):
    """Calculate Lennard-Jones energy for a given distance, with a cutoff."""
    if r_float == 0 or r_float >= cutoff_distance:
        return 0.0
    return 4 * epsilon * ((sigma / r_float) ** 12 - (sigma / r_float) ** 6)

def get_potential(index_int):
    """Calculate the Lennard-Jones potential for a single bead."""
    bead_potential_float = 0
    current_loc_pt = polymer_chain_vec[index_int]
    for i in range(len(polymer_chain_vec)):
        if i != index_int:
            other_loc_pt = polymer_chain_vec[i]
            r_float = get_distance(current_loc_pt, other_loc_pt)
            if r_float <= cutoff_distance:
                bead_potential_float += lj_energy_func(r_float)
    return bead_potential_float

def get_total_potential():
    """Calculate the total Lennard-Jones potential of the system."""
    total_potential_float = 0
    for i in range(len(polymer_chain_vec)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(polymer_chain_vec)):  # Only consider each pair once
            r_float = get_distance(polymer_chain_vec[i], polymer_chain_vec[j])
            if r_float <= cutoff_distance:
                total_potential_float += lj_energy_func(r_float)
    return total_potential_float

def initialize_polymer():
    """Initialize the polymer with random points within the boundary."""
    current_point_pt = [random.uniform(0, periodic_boundary_int), random.uniform(0, periodic_boundary_int)]
    polymer_chain_vec.append(current_point_pt)
    for _ in range(N - 1):
        while True:
            new_loc_pt = get_point_at_radius(current_point_pt, max_atom_distance_float)
            # Ensure no overlap
            if all(get_distance(new_loc_pt, existing_pt) >= sigma for existing_pt in polymer_chain_vec):
                polymer_chain_vec.append(new_loc_pt)
                current_point_pt = new_loc_pt
                break

def run_simulation(steps_int):
    """Run the Monte Carlo simulation."""
    total_pot_vec = []
    
    # Get the current timestamp
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    
    for step in range(steps_int):
        rand_index_int = random.randint(0, len(polymer_chain_vec) - 1)  # Choose a random index
        before_loc_pt = polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int]  # Current bead location
        before_pot_float = get_potential(rand_index_int)  # Current potential
        new_loc_pt = get_point_at_radius(before_loc_pt, max_atom_distance_float)  # Random new location
        polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int] = new_loc_pt  # Move bead
        after_pot_float = get_potential(rand_index_int)  # New potential
        pot_diff_float = after_pot_float - before_pot_float
        
        if pot_diff_float > 0:  # Metropolis criterion
            rand_float = random.random()
            if math.exp(-pot_diff_float / (k_B * temperature_float)) <= rand_float:
                polymer_chain_vec[rand_index_int] = before_loc_pt  # Reject move
        
        # Calculate and log total energy
        total_pot_double = get_total_potential()  # Energy in Joules
        energy_joules = total_pot_double  # Energy in Joules
        energy_kj_mol = (energy_joules * 1e3) / avogadro_number  # Convert to kJ/mol
        total_pot_vec.append(energy_kj_mol)

        # Log the total potential
        write_txt(f"total_energy_log_SI_{timestamp}.txt", f"{energy_kj_mol:.15f}\n")

        # Print progress to console with flushing
        print(f"Step {step + 1}/{steps_int}: Total Energy = {energy_kj_mol:.5f} kJ/mol", end='\r', flush=True)

    # Print a newline at the end to avoid overwriting the last line
    print("\nSimulation complete.")
    return total_pot_vec

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize_polymer()
    total_pot_vec = run_simulation(sim_steps_int)
    plt.plot(range(len(total_pot_vec)), total_pot_vec)
    plt.xlabel("Step")
    plt.ylabel("Total Lennard-Jones Potential (kJ/mol, Smoothed)")
    plt.title("Monte Carlo Simulation")
    plt.show()

```


That's a lot of code. Why not make a "minimum working example" or tell us specifically what you're doing or how you're trying to convert units?

Duplicate of https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/13727/7. Since the code is nicely divided into functions, it might help in debugging to generate some tests that each function is doing what you expect independently

The recommended way is to, firstly, setup all your equations to be dimensionless. If you cannot do that, then chose a unit system, write your equation in that system (taking care of all the constant you are using) and then keep looking that your inputs are in the desire unit system.

The script reads energy_kj_mol = (energy_joules * 1e3) / avogadro_number  # Convert to kJ/mol however shouldn't there a division over 1000 (rather than multiplication by 1000) when converting energy [J] to energy [kJ]? By a dimensional analysis, there might be an additional pitfall here; is energy_joules about a single molecule? If so, there should be a multiplication per mole (approx 6.022 x E23), and not a division either.
